# find a word/string that contains a q and not followed by a u

Tags: linux, grep

I'm looking to find a grep command to search for all words/string that contain the letter q that is not followed by a u directly after.

```
grep 'q!u' file
```

Comment: How do you define word/string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU `grep` implementation of `grep` that you have on Linux is able to use PCRE-style "negative look-ahead assertions".  PCRE is short for "Perl compatible regular expressions".  These are extensions to the standard POSIX regular expressions and the syntax for what you want to do looks like

```
q(?!u)
```

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -P 'q(?!u)' file
```

would find all lines that contains a `q` that is not followed (directly) by a `u`.

Further information on lookaround assertions with PCRE may be found at, for example

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

---

A POSIX standard regular expression could use

```
q[^u]
```

i.e., "a `q` followed (directly) by something that is not a `u`".  However, this pattern *also matches the non-`u` character*, whereas the expression with the negative look-ahead does not match the character after the `q`. This means that the above expression would not match a `q` at the end of a line, for example.  To do that, you could possibly use

```
q([^u]|$)
```

which is an extended regular expression (use `grep` with `-E` for this).

---

As for you "word/string":  A *word* is a string of *word characters*, usually characters matching `[[:alpha:]]`.  A *string* is *any* string.  The `q(?!u)` expression at the top would match *any string* that contained a `q` not followed (directly) by a `u`.

To match *words* containing a `q` but not the sequence `qu`, you could do either

```
grep -P -o -w '[[:alpha:]]*q(?!u)[[:alpha:]]*'
```

i.e. extract all complete words (only) that contains a `q` not followed by a `u`, or you could do it in two steps:

```
grep -o -w '[[:alpha:]]*q[[:alpha:]]*' | grep -v qu
```

This one would not require a PCRE (and hence no `-P`) and would get all words containing a `q` and then *remove* (with the second `grep`) the words that contained `qu`.

Example:

```
$ grep -o -w '[[:alpha:]]*q[[:alpha:]]*' /usr/share/dict/words  | grep -v qu
Iraq
Iraqi
Iraqian
Louiqa
miqra
nastaliq
Pontacq
q
qasida
qere
qeri
qintar
qoph
Saqib
shoq
Tareq
```

The PCRE variant would additionally return `zaqqum` as that contains a `q` not followed by a `u`.

Whichever way you do this depends on what your data looks like and what you actually want to match.

Comment: I wonder if "word ends in q" is a condition that needs to be matched

Comment: `grep -E 'q([^u]|$)'` (instead of `grep 'q[^u]'`) to catch a `q` at the end of a line

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks. Incorporated.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below awk command

example file

```
prqrtwtw
ahayqlo
prasqu
```

expected output

```
prqrtwtw
ahayqlo
```

command:

```
k=`awk -F "" '{print NF}' examplefile | sort -nr | sed -n '1p'`

for ((i=1;i<=$k;i++))
> do
> awk -v i="$i" -F "" '$i=="q" && $(i+1) !="u"  {print $0}' examplefile;done




output

prqrtwtw
ahayqlo
```